# bash insert a string variable to a string(another variable) at specific location

Tags: bash

I have these 2 variables

```
to_insert="John"
full_string="My name is and I am 25 years old"
```

I would like to insert the value of "to_insert" into "full_string" after the word/string "is".
Basically I want to get this in the end:

```
full_string="My name is John and I am 25 years old"
```

would appreciate your help,
Alon

Comment: You should add an anchor to `full_string`, something along the lines of `full_string='My name is #{NAME} and I am 25 years old'; full_string="${full_string/"#{NAME}"/John}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed "s/\(.*is\)/\1 $to_insert/" <<< "$full_string"
My name is John and I am 25 years old
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Parameter Expansion - Substitution:

```sh
#! /bin/bash
to_insert="John"
full_string="My name is and I am 25 years old"
echo "${full_string/ is / is "$to_insert" }"
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
to_insert='John'
full_string='My name is and I am 25 years old'
prefix='My name is'

even_fuller_string="${full_string::${#prefix}} ${to_insert} ${full_string:${#prefix} + 1}"
echo "$even_fuller_string"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bash to search for "is" and replace it with "is $to_insert":

```sh
to_insert="John"
full_string="My name is and I am 25 years old"
full_string=${full_string/is/is $to_insert}
echo $full_string
```

Output:

```
My name is John and I am 25 years old
```

Reference:
Search for "${parameter/pattern/string}" in https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html

Answer (score -1):

You can simply expand the 'to_insert' variable inside 'full_string' like this:

`full_string="My name is $to_insert and I am 25 years old"`